# GIT not working anymore from Visual Studio Code's integrated Terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After updating Visual Studio Code to the latest version i noticed that the GIT integration stoped working for me. I can stage changes and commit but trying to push or pull to my remote repository results in the following error message:

```
'G:\Path\To\Repository\' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The exact same error appears if i type `git pull origin master:master` into the integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code. The problem appears on ever repository that im using.

However opening Widows Powershell, going to the exact same directory and executing `git pull origin master:master` works perfectly fine (which is strange because the integrated terminal is essentially just powershell)

Also using external tools like Tortoise GIT works perfectly fine.

This seems to be a problem with Visual Studio Code and not with my Repository.

Comment: I suggest you ask this in the VS Code repository's issues.